# Avoid truncating leading plus sign from a string

Tags: c#

```
DataTable dt = {a DataTable containing one column of strings in this format: "+12394837444"}
```

all members have leading plus sign, this DataTable consists of these members and has one column only. i want to take a string from this table in complete form with this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
                {
                    System.Data.DataRow drow = dt.Rows[j];
                    string total = drow.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString();
                }
if(total.StartsWith("+"))
   {
    // we are ok
   }
else
   {
    string edited = "+" + total;
   }
```

but this truncates the leading plus sign and since these are not of kind double or number then the ToString() has no overloads to define the plus sign to not remove. it is necessary to have plus sign but the ItemArray.Getvalue().ToString() removes it always. how i prevent this and get the leading sign too?

Comment: Is `drow.ItemArray.GetValue(0)` really a string or is it some numeric type? In the latter case you have to use String.Format() with a format string including the + sign

Comment: What is the type of `drow.ItemArray.GetValue(0)`?

Comment: u know, the problem is that when i take the number i have to check that if it has the plus sign inside it not adding from String.Format(). in fact i don't want to manipulate i just want to know if it has plus sign or not. i have to check that the number has the plus sign or not, if yes then it is ok and if no then i have add a leading 1 to it

Comment: here is the ItemArray:   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.itemarray.aspx

Comment: @HosseinAmini Sorry if I was not clear. I don't mean the type it is boxed as (`Object`), but what do you get when you do `drow.ItemArray.GetValue(0).GetType()`?

Comment: i get the string without the plus sign, it gives the string just removes its + and does not accept .ToString() overloads so i cant give it the format

Comment: @HosseinAmini Note the `.GetType()` in lc's comment - the idea is to determine the *type*, not the *value*, i.e. whether it's actually stored in the DataTable as a *string* or as a *number*.

Comment: the type is System.Int64

Comment: so it is the cause of truncating the + sign, right?

Comment: Yes. If your data actually has a numeric *type* (rather than being a string representation of numbers), then there *is* no leading + sign; the numbers are simply positive. Your DataTable needs to be populated with strings instead.

Comment: yes, thank you shambulator and Ic for bringing it to my attention, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Either store it as a string with the leading +, or just add it like this:

```
string total = "+" + drow.ItemArray.GetValue(0);
```

**Edit**

Not sure what the type is, but you can check if the + sign is already there:

```
string total = drow.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString();
if (total.IndexOf('+') != 0) {
    total = "+" + total;
}
```

Comment: i want to check if it has the plus sign itself , i want to check that if it has the sign itself then the number is ok and if it has not then i add a +1 to it

Comment: this line : drow.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString() removes the + sign. i have checked it in debugging mode. just it saves the number itself when doint that ToString() part